# What are some alternatives to RedirectToAction?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, controller, redirecttoaction

On my `HomeController` I have an index action which redirects to the index action of the `CustomerController` via the `RedirectToAction` method. In this instance I don't like how `RedirectToAction` modifies the URL showing `mysite.com/Customer`. Are there some alternative mechanisms to performing a redirection that will allow me to still leverage the index action from the `CustomerController`?

```
public RedirectToRouteResult Index()
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Customer");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood it, RedirectToAction uses a reverse lookup on the routing table to generate its URL.  So if you've told the Routing module that you want to map "/Customer/Index" to Controller Customer and Action Index then RedirectToAction will take your Index and Customer arguments and convert them to "/Customer/Index".

So if you want to change the behaviour of RedirectToAction you simply need to change your routing rules.